# Angular ng-repeat to create a table issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

I am using ng-repeat to set all the rows I need but I also have some inputs. However, I need to differentiate between each row so that if a checkbox is selected in one, it isn't selected in the others as it does now. I am sure I am missing something simple here, but it just isn't coming to me. My code:

```
<form class="beneEnroll" name="enrollForm" novalidate ng-model="electionData">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>your plan year election</th>
                <th>pay check deduction amount</th>
                <th>NaviCard (no cost)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="benefit in oe.oeBenefits">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="electInfo.deleted"></td>
                <td>{{ benefit.benefitName }}</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="claimAmount" data-ng-model="electInfo.annualElection" ng-required="true" navia-min="0.01" navia-max="10000" ng-pattern="/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/"></td>
                <td>{{benefit.numberOfContributions}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="electInfo.isDebitCard"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models should refer to the items in the array being looped

```
<tbody ng-repeat="benefit in oe.oeBenefits">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="benefit.deleted"></td>
        <td>{{ benefit.benefitName }}</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="claimAmount" data-ng-model="benefit.annualElection" ng-required="true" navia-min="0.01" navia-max="10000" ng-pattern="/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/"></td>
        <td>{{benefit.numberOfContributions}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="benefit.isDebitCard"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

After changing the position of the models, the way you access them should update, as well.

Comment: are you saying I should simple remove 'ng-model' from each? Since this is being looped, what would be the best way to approach that if you will?

Comment: As shown in the code snippet, the way to do this would be assigning the `ng-model`s  to the looped item `benefit`, instead of shared variables in the controller, so that you can have different values for different items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/2zypp97g/). You just need to move your input models into part of benefit array.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <form class="beneEnroll" name="enrollForm" novalidate ng-model="electionData">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>your plan year election</th>
                <th>pay check deduction amount</th>
                <th>NaviCard (no cost)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="benefit in oe.oeBenefits">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="benefit.deleted"></td>
                <td>{{ benefit.benefitName }}</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="claimAmount" data-ng-model="benefit.annualElection" ng-required="true" navia-min="0.01" navia-max="10000" ng-pattern="/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/"></td>
                <td>{{benefit.numberOfContributions}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="beneElect" data-ng-value="false" ng-model="benefit.isDebitCard"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.oe = {oeBenefits : [
      {
        benefitName: 'benefit1',
        numberOfContributions: 10,
        deleted : false,
        annualElection:100, 
        isDebitCard: false 
      },
      {
        benefitName: 'benefit2',
        numberOfContributions: 20,
        deleted : false,
        annualElection:100, 
        isDebitCard: false 
      },
      {
        benefitName: 'benefit3',
        numberOfContributions: 30,
        deleted : false,
        annualElection:100, 
        isDebitCard: false 
      }
    ]}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding ng-model to the same value i.e. electInfo.deleted.  So every time you change the value of electInfo.deleted all your checkboxes are just reflecting this value.

To do what you are asking, you will need to separate this out into directives.  This way each directive created will have an isolated scope and will be independent of each other.